# Why is this Public Function in a Module not accessible

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, module, access-modifiers

I have an assembly comprised of several useful little utilities.  Within that I have a module Containing a simple Public Function.

```
Module FishTrackerConfigurations

Public Function GetValueOfUseProductId As Boolean
    Return VtlGetUseProductId 'A simple private routine in the same module
End Function
End Module
```

When I call this function from another project (in which this assembly is referenced I get the following error.

```
Error   BC30390 'FishTrackerConfigurations.Public Function GetValueOfUseProductId() As Boolean' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Public'.
```

The function is being called from within my projects Application.Xaml.VB file, specifically in the Protected Overrides Sub OnStartup(e As StartupEventArgs) routine.

I'd like to know why this happens.

Comment: This can also burn you if you're trying to unit test a function from a module.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Although the *method* is `Public`, the *Module* (by default) is not.

You need to specify this explicitly:

```
Public Module FishTrackerConfigurations
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, I'd always assumed Modules were public by default, I'll take that as today's new lesson learnt.  You'll have to wait a short while before I can accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no other way to thank Matt Wilko for the answer - since i can't neither comment nor upvote due to a lack of reputation - but i never expected to see something like "Function is not accessible in this context because it is 'Public'",

and i was like

```
throw new COMException("wait - what?!", HRESULT.E_UNEXPECTED)
```