# C# RDLC Report Viewer LocalReport Execute crashes

Tags: c#, .net-core, rdlc, localreport

I am trying to render a byte array from an RDLC file. I've done it successfully with one .rdlc but I am having issues with another. Below is my code.

```
    Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    parameters.Add("ShowStates","2020");
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
    LocalReport report = new LocalReport(rdlcFilePath);

    var DS1 = await GetStatusReportwithFileCounts(ReportYear);
    var DS2 = GetOverallStatus(ReportYear, DS1);
    report.AddDataSource("Status_reports_SummaryDB", DS1);
    report.AddDataSource("Overall", DS2);
    var result = report.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, 1, parameters);
    return result.MainStream;
```

I know my DataSources are returning good data and my rdlc path is correct. For reference, we are using .Net Core, so my report rendering options seem limited. I assume the error lies within something in the .rdlc file it's self. I guess my greatest issue is I'm not really sure how to interpret the error message (Below). Any insight on where to look for errors would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It looks like there are objects that are not accessible due to them being scoped as Friend. This link may help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713099/why-is-this-public-function-in-a-module-not-accessible

Comment: As far as I know,  not too long ago net core could not  proceed rdlc reports. Do you have any another reports that are working properly?

Comment: Yeah I have another that works fine, I tried to compare the two xml files but they seemed very different.

Comment: @GingerMattRogers I tried it 2 years ago, and had a lot of problem, since one format was uncopatible with another. Finally I created net 4.8 project with API returning reports. I found it the most reliable.

Comment: .NET Core RDLC is not official. This can only be solve by the library author, who's last active status is a few years ago.